# Prolog, getting right answer in terminal, but wrong answer when running a program

Tags: prolog, iso-prolog, prolog-toplevel

Typing "prolog" in terminal gets:

```
GNU Prolog 1.3.0

By Daniel Diaz

Copyright (C) 1999-2007 Daniel Diaz

| ?-
```

Typing:

```
| ?- member(2, [1,2,3]).
```

Gets:

```
true ?
```

Then pressing enter gets:

```
yes
```

Typing:

```
| ?- member(4, [1,2,3]).
```

gets:

```
no
```

When i write a file; test.pl consisting of this:

```
:- member(4, [1,2,3]), nl, halt.
```

And then write in the terminal:

```
| ?- [test2].
```

I get:

```
compiling /path/test.pl for byte code...
/path/test.pl:1: warning: unknown directive (',')/2 - maybe use initialization/1 - directive ignored
/path/test.pl compiled, 1 lines read - 139 bytes written, 11 ms

yes
```

Shouldnt the answer here be no? What am i doing wrong. Also, how would you do this in prolog:

```
if (testInPrologTerminal(member(4, [1,2,3])) { do this; }
```

I.e, i want to send queries to the prolog top level, and get an answer

Comment: You might want to note that the most recent version of GNU is 1.4.4.

Answer (score 3):

When you type the query `member(2, [1,2,3])`, GNU Prolog prompts you for a possible additional solution (hence the `true ?` prompt) as only by backtracking (and looking to the last element in the list, 3) it could check for it. When you press enter, you're telling the top-level interpreter that you are satisfied with the current solution (the element 2 in the list second position). The second query, `member(4, [1,2,3])`, have no solutions so you get a `no`.

To execute a query when a file is loaded, the standard and portable way of doing it, is to use the standard `initialization/1` directive. In this case, you would write:

```
:- initialization((member(4, [1,2,3]), nl, halt)).
```

Note the ()'s surrounding the query, otherwise you may get a warning about an unknown `initialization/3` standard, built-in, control construct. If you have more complex queries to be executed when a file is loaded, then define a predicate that makes the queries a call this predicate from the `initialization/1` directive. For example:

```
main :-
    (   member(4, [1,2,3]) ->
        write('Query succeeded!'), nl
    ;   write('Query failed!'), nl
    ).

:- initialization(main).
```

Writing arbitrary queries as directives in a source file is legacy practice and thus accepted by several Prolog implementations but using the `initialization/1` directive is the more clean, standard, and portable alternative.

Comment: Why "trying to redefine the (',')/2 standard built-in"? Without the additional parentheses it seems just as (unknown) initialization/3 call